# chmod 400 command in anaconda powershell prompt is throwing an exception

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, anaconda, powershell-3.0

chmod 400 command in anaconda powershell prompt is throwing an "CommandNotFoundException"

(base) PS C:\Users> chmod 400 keypair1.pem                                                                                                                             chmod : The term 'chmod' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- chmod +r keypair1.pem
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (chmod:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: I might be wrong here, but `chmod` is UNIX/Linux technology, while Powershell is Windows, or am I mistaking?

Comment: @Dominique you are right? `chmod` is **ix technology!

Comment: @Dominique.  Powershell is available on GNU/Linux.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod command is not available in PowerShell at Window 11.
In Window there is command: [icacls][1] in Window. icacls can do everything that chmod can do in Unix. try command to change mod 400.

Step 1: icacls.exe fileName /reset
Step 2: icacls.exe fileName /grant:r userName:(r)

r -> read only and equivalent: 400
 
  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls
```